# setTimeOut scope in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, settimeout

I have a notification functionality in my chrome extension which is managed by a background page (background.html)
This page calls the setNotificationDelay() function which is basically a deletion of the previous timer followed by a setTimeOut.

```
function setNotificationDelay() {
    clearNotificationTimer();
    newDelay = getNotificationDelay()
    notificationTimer = setTimeout(showNotification, newDelay);
    }
}
```

I have also an options.html page which allows the configuration of the notification hour. I want to modify the background timeout when the configuration is modified, but when I call the setNotificationDelay() from the Option page it doesn't work, and I presume it's because the scope of the timers are attached to the parent page.

If I let the Option page opens the timeout is triggered, if I close it the notification never happened.

How can I attach this timer to the background page ?
Is there a better way to achieve it ?

Thanks.

EDIT: The chrome.extension have the getBackground page method which returns the window object for the background page:

```
function setNotificationDelay() {
    clearNotificationTimer();
    newDelay = getNotificationDelay()
    notificationTimer = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().setTimeout(showNotification, newDelay);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`options.js` is only active while the `options.html` page is open, and I presume you don't want to leave the page open while you're waiting for the notification.  What you want (I think) is to have `background.js` set the notification (both `background.js` and `options.js` access the same string variable `localStorage.yourNotificationDelay`).

One thing to watch out for is that if you are using [event pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html) instead of background pages, a notification of more than a few seconds won't happen because Chrome will unload the background page.  In that case, you'll need to use [alarms](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html) instead.

**Edit:** Your edit makes me think I'm not understanding you.  Perhaps you're expecting the user to change the interval while the timer is running?  Then I'd recommend sending a [message](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to `background.js` with `newDelay`, and use that to call `setNotificationDelay()`.